# Diferença entre varias datas na mesma coluna

Tags: powerbi, dax

Estou com o seguinte problema..

Possuo a seguinte tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desejo criar uma coluna calculada que me diga a diferença de dias entre duas datas do mesmo código (**COD**), as diferença deverá ser calculada baseada na data anterior a da linha. Por exemplo:

Utilizando o **COD** *B*

**COD |     DATE**  | *Dias de Diferença*

B |05/01/2018 |

B |09/01/2018 | *4*

B |12/01/2018 | *3*

No exemplo da imagem os códigos/datas estão ordenados em sequencia, porém, na realidade estão fora de ordem.

Tentei utilizar a seguinte sentença em DAX:

```
DATEDIFF(Testing[DATE]; FIRSTDATE(FILTER( ALL(Testing[DATE]) ;Testing[DATE] > EARLIER(Testing[DATE])));DAY)
```

*Explicando oque tentei:*
 Realizar a diferença entre a data na linha e utilizando a função *EARLIER* pegar a data mais recente fora a atual.

Porém, obtive o seguinte resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não estou conseguindo colocar como filtro o **COD**, para que a analise de 'EARLIER' seja realizada somente no mesmo 'grupo', pelo que entendi o PowerBI está considerando todas as datas.

Alguma ideia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após algumas tentativas, perguntei também no SO. E obtive a seguinte solução que funcionou muito bem, e pode ser encontrada de forma completa aqui:

[Difference between multiple dates in the same column based on category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54044455/difference-between-multiple-dates-in-the-same-column-based-on-category)

Eis a solução:

```
Days_diff =
VAR StartDate =
    CALCULATE (
        LASTDATE ( Testing[DATE] ),
        FILTER (
            ALLEXCEPT ( Testing, Testing[COD] ),
            Testing[DATE] < EARLIER ( Testing[DATE] )
        )
    )
RETURN
    DATEDIFF ( StartDate, Testing[DATE], DAY )
```

E a explicação fornecida pelo usuário **Alexis**..

"A variável **StartDate** calcula a última data antes da data da linha atual. Eu uso o **CALCULATE** para remover todo o contexto da linha, exceto **COD**, já que é nisso que estamos agrupando.

Nota: A função **EARLIER** não é uma função de data / hora, mas sim uma referência a um contexto de linha anterior (antes de entrar na função **FILTER**). Isso nos permite retornar um nível quando estamos aninhando funções.

Então você apenas pega o **DATEDIFF**.